# Get id value using <input> with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, jquery, filepicker.io

First example:

```
var dbSelected = "File selected: ";
var filenamePanel = document.getElementById('filenamePanel');
filenamePanel.textContent = dbSelected + files[0].name;

var postLink = files[0].link;
document.getElementById('postLink').value = postLink;

var postName = files[0].name;
document.getElementById('postName').value = postName;
```

If I use `<input type="hidden" name="postName" id="postName">` to send the value to another page via POST with PHP, it works.

Second example:

```
function onSuccessCallback(Blob){
    document.getElementById('postName').textContent = Blob.filename;
    document.getElementById('postLink').textContent = Blob.url;
    document.getElementById('results').textContent = JSON.stringify(Blob);            
};
```

Now, If I use `<input type="hidden" name="postName" id="postName">` on the second example to send the 'postName' id value to another page, the value is empty.

What changes are necessary, on the second example, so that I can send the 'postName' id value to another page using a hidden `<input>` field?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.value` instead of `.textContent` to store the data in the hidden input field:

```
document.getElementById('postName').value= Blob.filename;
```

Comment: please accept the answer when your problem is solved.